# How to print output on same line in dart Pad ? I am unable to stdout.write('hello');

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

```
import 'dart:io';
main()
{
 stdout.write('hi, ');
 stdout.write('hello');
}
```

// Unable to use the stdout,write() on dart Io Pad ? 
//Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: StdIOUtils._getStdioOutputStream

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because DartPad does not support `dart:io`.

Also, DartPad does not support libraries from packages. DartPad supports `dart:*` libraries that work with web apps.

If you want to use `dart:io` you'll need to install Dart SDK on your computer or on a virtual machine on the cloud.

https://dart.dev/tools/dartpad#library-support

Answer (score 1):

**By using the direct print() method (Support to Dartpad)**

```
void main() {
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      print('Text ' * i);
   }
}

Output:
Text 
Text Text 
Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text
```

*Example for when multiplying by 0, 1, 2*

```
void main() {
  print('Text' * 1);
  print('Text' * 0);
  print('Text' * 2);
}

Output:
Text

TextText
```